# Messed up color profiles in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, crash, color

For some unknown reason, my color profiles are messed up in way that whenever an application (e.g. pixelmator, Preview, Xcode, etc.) tries loading Adobe RGB 1998 color profile (probably any other color profile too for that matter), that application will crash miserably.

I sent a report to apple, but so far have received nothing. What pixelmator support told me, is that for some reason "ColorSync Utility" won't show up Adobe RGB 1998 profile under "System" section, although AdobeRGB1998.icc file is in "/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/".  Therefore applications that try loading it will fail to do so, resulting in a crash:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff8ffc25a2 color_space_create_adobe_rgb_1998 + 23
1   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff9019abf1 CGColorSpaceCreateAdobeRGB1998 + 22
2   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff8fddf6dd CGColorSpaceCreateWithName + 828
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b07b9a7 +[NSColorSpace specialColorSpaceWithID:] + 83
4   com.pixelmatorteam.pixelmator   0x0000000100089c7e 0x100000000 + 564350
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eeba47a _CFXNotificationPost + 2554
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ac5a846 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b0cb60d -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 292
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b0cb346 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 216
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b0c8532 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 566
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b0c812c -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 351
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ac7412b -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 308
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ac73f8d _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 106
13  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8dfa6b48 aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 307
14  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8dfa69a9 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 37
15  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8dfa6869 aeProcessAppleEvent + 318
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff922028e9 AEProcessAppleEvent + 100
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b0c4916 _DPSNextEvent + 1456
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b0c3ed2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b0bb283 -[NSApplication run] + 517
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b05fcb6 NSApplicationMain + 869
21  com.pixelmatorteam.pixelmator   0x0000000100002854 0x100000000 + 10324
```

I am wondering if anyone else has had this, or a similar problem, and what is your suggested fix?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the Parameter Ram? (holding cmd+alt+p+r on startup)

Comment: Do you think that would reset color profiles, etc.?

Comment: NVRAM reset won't change a thing, unfortunately! ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I had to fresh install Mac OS X to fix this.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept this answer (by clicking the checkmark on the left side)